# Portal site connection node not showing in SiteMapPath breadcrumb

Tags: 2010, development, breadcrumb

I have several site collections with portal site connections set pointing to a root site collection.
In my custom master page i have added a SiteMapPath breadcrumb, based on the breadcrumb from the night and day master, here is the markup:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath    
    runat="server"
    SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
    RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
    NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode"
    CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode"
    RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode"
    HideInteriorRootNodes="false" 
    SkipLinkText="">
    <PathSeparatorTemplate>
        <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow ID="ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrowBreadCrumb" runat="server" Visible="true"/>
    </PathSeparatorTemplate>
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

On my dev machine this works perfectly and i see the portal site as the root node in the bread-crumb. Now I have gone to a test environment and the portal site no longer shows (it is still showing in the SharePoint drop down bread crumb in the ribbon). The site collections concerned where set up exactly the same way so i can't figure out what could be wrong. 
Is there anything at the web application, or farm levels that could effect this, or possibly something in the hive that is effecting it?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: toby, did you create a custom sitemap datasource ? If yes, where did you save the xml file. If it was somewhere at 14 hive folder you will need to copy the same in the test environment.

Comment: Hi Moss, I didn't create a custom sitemap XML. Do you know how i would specify the location if i were to use one?